# To what extent do we help out malicious hackers?

Tags: discussion, ethics

So the question is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371483/i-want-to-display-my-installation-package-look-like-an-image

The person changed their question after I gave them the hint "for educational purposes", the original is this:

**Hide .exe file in .jpg**

> I was looking any proper way that i can use in my c# code which will show current .exe file as .jpg file to user? (hides exe file so that user can not understand the filetype) 
>   i know it can be done with several mouse clicks, but is there any way to do it programmatically, if yes then how?

The edited version is this:

**I want to display my installation package look like an image**

> I have a project Key Logger as my class project, I have completed all the tasks but only one thing is remaining which is displaying an image file instead of package installer. I know it is harmful but I want to do it for study purpose rather than to harm people!
>   any ideas regarding this will be appreciated. Thank you!

It doesn't take a rocket scientist to see this person is malicious. Should we refrain from answering hacking questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143617/495455) when even Jeff Atwood blogs about them?

I'm feeling unethical about it now and am thinking I need some advice to be able to draw a line in the sand to distinguish between helping a white or (in this case) a black hatter. Problem is the information is available online, so the line is blurry.

I was hoping one of you guys could tell me what the rules are on helping hackers and Stackoverflows ethics on this subject?

Comment: There is a certain beauty in leaving it up to the community. If it's obviously malicious, I tend to downvote. Many others do, too.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great thread, I did search before I asked and will probably adopt @RobertHarvey 's approach on this topic: **close if it's crap, or if it clearly intends to harm someone else** (in 4 more C# votes to get gold).

Comment: Regardless, I wouldn't advise on encouraging low quality questions like that by giving them an answer. Had the user shown some effort on their own part then it would have been clearer what their actual intent is

Comment: @Sayse yes, you're right and I should have commented "in a couple of clicks" though whats done is done and the guy had a couple of hundred points. This is why I am feeling bad about it.

Comment: I down and close vote anything that might even be remotely connected to malware.  ALL such questions are claimed to be from whlte hats & similar, ie. developers who would not ask such questions on a public site.

Comment: Like Robert Ulbricht? Thanks for your comment @MartinJames, this person who asked this is a real piece of work. I'm deleting my answer and voting to Delete the question.

Comment: LOL,..... yes:)